# Refer to own type in Kotlin object member

Tags: kotlin

I have some `object`s like so:

```
interface Maker<T : Thing>

interface Thing
```

I want `Thing` to hold a reference to its `Maker`, but I can't figure out how:

```
interface Thing {
    val maker: Maker<this::class> // ??
}
```

so that I can have something like:

```
class BallMaker : Maker<Ball>

object Ball : Thing {
    override val maker = BallMaker
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `Maker` refers to an instance whereas `maker = BallMaker` indicates that you want to reference a class? Also I don't think that this is possible with Kotlin's type system, but I'm here to be proven wrong :) (And even if it works somehow, one of the references has to be nullable / late inited during initialization) ... Oh, maybe `interface Thing<I, T: Maker<I>>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the perspective of `Thing`, its maker must be defined as simply `Maker<*>`, meaning any kind of maker at all.

You could parameterize `Thing` with the subclass.

```
interface Maker<T : Thing<T>> {
}

interface Thing<T : Thing<T>> {
    val maker: Maker<T>
}

class Ball : Thing<Ball> {
    override val maker: Maker<Ball>
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I need the `Thing`s to be objects, and this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you define your `Maker` interface like so:

```
interface Maker<out T : Thing>
    fun make(): T
}
```

Then your `Thing` interface can be defined as:

```
interface Thing {
    val maker: Maker<Thing>
}
```

Due to the use of `out`, implementations can be defined as:

```
class BallMaker : Maker<Ball> {
    override fun make(): Ball = TODO("not implemented")
}

class Ball : Thing {
    override val maker = BallMaker()
}
```

Here, the `maker` property will be of type `BallMaker`. You could also use:

```
override val maker: Maker<Ball> = BallMaker()
```

If you would rather expose the interface type instead of the implementation.

---

See [Generics: in, out, where - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) for more information on generics in Kotlin. An important thing to know about using `out` is that:

> The general rule is: when a type parameter `T` of a class `C` is declared **out**, it may occur only in **out**-position in the members of `C`, but in return `C<Base>` can safely be a supertype of `C<Derived>`.

In other words, if a generic parameter is defined with `out` it can only be used as return types, not parameter types. The opposite is true of `in`.

---

Of course, if your `Maker` interface only has one method you may want to consider using a function type instead.

```
interface Thing {
    val maker: () -> Thing
}
```

This will still allow you to do:

```
class Ball : Thing {
    // type can be inferred to "() -> Ball" instead in this case
    override val maker: () -> Ball = { Ball() }
}
```

If you want to name the function type, use a [type alias](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html).